# Converting Similar names to canonical form in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, canonicalization

I have a database of books. There can be situations where an author can use variations of their names as author.

For eg. Albert Einstein can be written as Albert E. or A. Einstein

Now I need to create a method such that SQL database and tell me the ID of the author based on such situations.

Is there a built in way to convert these multiple variations of a name into a single type within SQL language such as PostgreSQL?

Or Should I change the name using some another language such as C, C++ or Python to convert the name into a particular form and then send to database?

I would rather have a method within SQL instead of using some another language

Comment: What does this have to do with C++ **and** Python?  Are you using both languages?  Which single language do you want your answer in?  Adjust your language tags as appropriate.

Comment: I have added both languages as I want to know if there is any provision in both the languages and then choose

Answer (score 0):

You could use PostgreSQL full text search with a [thesaurus dictionary](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-dictionaries.html#TEXTSEARCH-THESAURUS).  The configuration file would then contain

```
Albert E. : Albert Einstein
A. Einstein : Albert Einstein
```

Comment: This would have to be done manually for all names right? Can we do this while inserting data into the database

Comment: You'd have to do that before you insert the data. And I don't see how but manually that could be done.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia says:

Soundex is a phonetic algorithm for indexing names by sound, as pronounced in English. The goal is for homophones to be encoded to the same representation so that they can be matched despite minor differences in spelling.[1] The algorithm mainly encodes consonants; a vowel will not be encoded unless it is the first letter. Soundex is the most widely known of all phonetic algorithms (in part because it is a standard feature of popular database software such as DB2, PostgreSQL,[2] MySQL,[3] SQLite,[4] Ingres, MS SQL Server,[5] Oracle.[6] and SAP ASE.[7]) Improvements to Soundex are the basis for many modern phonetic algorithms

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex

Answer (score 0):

When doing something like this:

```
select 
   id, 
   (Author) as Author,
   sum(case when length(name)>2 
            then 1 
            else 0 end) score
from 
   books 
   left join unnest(pg_catalog.string_to_array('Albert Einstein', ' ')) name
         on Author like '%'||name||'%'
group by id
order by score DESC
```

The `unnest()` returns the parts `Albert` and `Einstein` from the name `Albert Einstein`, and a score s counted. Higher the scores are most likely a match.

It returns:

| id | author | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Albert Einstein | 2 |
| 2 | A. Einstein | 1 |
| 3 | Albert E. | 1 |
| 4 | Anne Ellit | 0 |
| 6 | Arthur Eddington | 0 |
| 5 | Allan W. Eckert | 0 |

For complete SQL, see [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d16a2e18e9923c0ca036b4cc54facb18)

There is, of course, room for improvement in this script because an author like 'Albert Camus' or 'Siegfried Einstein' also get a score of 1 in this code.